Filter out values in a range that appear in a different range with other dimensions
I have a row in Google Sheets that I want to filter for the values that have an entry below them in the second row. Then I want to further filter for only those values that don't appear in a range with very different dimensions.
I hope this is clear, you can find a minimal example in this sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1v1OKg-iQ92KsYHabCzkd6A7980H4uet34XhJRqGR0D0/edit?usp=sharing
I guess I just have to add an additional condition to the filter function, but have struggled to find a suitable one because FILTER expects conditions with the same range as the range to be filtered. Do you have a simple suggestion for how to do this, preferably without using "intermediate" cells or scripting?

Are cells B6,B7,C6 the expected output? What does other/different dimensions mean?

Thanks for the question. No, they are the values that should still be filtered out of the prefiltered set of values. I've slightly modified the example – the desired output would now be {8 9}.


You may try:
=filter(B1:J1,B2:J2,isna(xmatch(B1:J1,tocol(B6:C8,1))))



That's great, thank you! I knew neither XMATCH nor TOCOL – especially TOCOL is very elegant and useful!
Can't say I fully understand your formula and what XMATCH does compared to MATCH, but as long as it works I'll just accept it ;)

Follow-up question (I've changed the sheet again): What if the cells in column C with the values that I want to filter out additionally have content like "5, 10", i.e. two values separated by a comma and a space. Is there still a way to make this work?

formula updated

Really like it – very simple and elegant. Thanks again for your help!
